# Match multiple line breaks with regex in JMeter Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter, line-breaks

I try to use regex to extract text from text response, which contains multiple line breaks.

Sample text:

```
                                    <td class="comment-text">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum, 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

I use this regex: https://regex101.com/r/jNyALD/1

Comment: You could just share the regex code of yours as text here. A total third-party link dependency as it is now.

Comment: What is the text you need to extract? The inner text up to the first comma? Try `<td class="comment-text">\s*([^<",]*)[^<]*<\/td>\s*<\/tr>`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/jNyALD/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the boundaries in [regex](https://regex101.com/r/EwyYnF/1)

```
<td class="comment-text">([^<]+)<\/td>
```

Notice you can also use [Boundary Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor)

> Allows the user to extract values from a server response using left and right boundaries.